# Do I need to 'create'/initialize local variables if they are just used as pointers to form controls?

Tags: delphi, compiler-warnings, delphi-xe7, tscrollbox

I have this simple example of syncing Scrollboxes, where I control which side is synced by Radio button - Sync Left or Right side. When I compile, I get compiler messages:

> [dcc32 Warning] Unit1.pas(51): W1036 Variable 'ScrlBox1' might not have been initialized
>
> [dcc32 Warning] Unit1.pas(51): W1036 Variable 'ScrlBox2' might not have been initialized

This is the simple example:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ScrlBox1, ScrlBox2: TScrollBox;
begin

    if radiobtn_SyncLeftSides.Checked then // Snyc Left side
    begin
      ScrlBox1 := ScrollBoxLeft1;
      ScrlBox2 := ScrollBoxLeft2;
    end
    else if radiobtn_SyncrightSides.Checked then  // Snyc Right side
    begin
      ScrlBox2 := ScrollBoxRight1;
      ScrlBox1 := ScrollBoxRight2;
    end;

    // Sync scroll boxes
    ScrlBox2.VertScrollBar.Position := ScrlBox1.VertScrollBar.Position;
    ScrlBox2.HorzScrollBar.Position := ScrlBox1.HorzScrollBar.Position;

end;
```

What is the issue here?

If I add this at the beginning the message is gone:

```
ScrlBox1:= TScrollBox.Create(nil);
ScrlBox2:= TScrollBox.Create(nil);
```

but I don't think creating scroll box variables is necessary, right? These are just variable pointers to controls on form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If *both* `radiobtn_SyncLeftSides` and `radiobtn_SyncrightSides` are unchecked, you are not initializing the `ScrlBox1` and `ScrlBox2` variables before using them.  That is what the compiler is complaining about.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ScrlBox1, ScrlBox2: TScrollBox;
begin
  if radiobtn_SyncLeftSides.Checked then // Snyc Left side
  begin
    ScrlBox1 := ScrollBoxLeft1;
    ScrlBox2 := ScrollBoxLeft2;
  end
  else if radiobtn_SyncrightSides.Checked then  // Snyc Right side
  begin
    ScrlBox2 := ScrollBoxRight1;
    ScrlBox1 := ScrollBoxRight2;
  end else
  begin
    // NOT INITIALIZED HERE!!!!!
  end;

  // Sync scroll boxes
  ScrlBox2.VertScrollBar.Position := ScrlBox1.VertScrollBar.Position;
  ScrlBox2.HorzScrollBar.Position := ScrlBox1.HorzScrollBar.Position;
end;
```

If you don't want to sync the scrolling, you should just `Exit` the procedure:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ScrlBox1, ScrlBox2: TScrollBox;
begin
  if radiobtn_SyncLeftSides.Checked then // Snyc Left side
  begin
    ScrlBox1 := ScrollBoxLeft1;
    ScrlBox2 := ScrollBoxLeft2;
  end
  else if radiobtn_SyncrightSides.Checked then  // Snyc Right side
  begin
    ScrlBox2 := ScrollBoxRight1;
    ScrlBox1 := ScrollBoxRight2;
  end else
  begin
    Exit; // <-- HERE
  end;

  // Sync scroll boxes
  ScrlBox2.VertScrollBar.Position := ScrlBox1.VertScrollBar.Position;
  ScrlBox2.HorzScrollBar.Position := ScrlBox1.HorzScrollBar.Position;
end;
```

Comment: Interesting, didn't think about this because I make sure one of the radio buttons is always checked by default, so this should never happen. Is there a way to avoid third execution branch?

Comment: @Mike: Remy answered that - see the sentence between the two code blocks in his answer.

Comment: OK, Exit seems to be the way to do it. I'm trying to avoid it as it looks odd, but maybe I'm just not used to using Exit - the reason for these compiler messages.

Comment: I just accepted your answer, in case it gets deleted, so you get the points.

Comment: If one of the two radio buttons is *always* checked, then you shouldn't need to inspect *both*. Replace the second `if` clause with a simple `else` instead: `if radiobtn_SyncLeftSides.Checked then {...} else {...}`.

Comment: Thank you @RobKennedy, I like your suggestion. It fits better for this example, and Exit will fit better when I have more than just 2 options.

Comment: The alternative is to use a `TRadioGroup` instead of individual `TRadioButton`s, and then make decisions based on the `TRadioGroup.ItemIndex` property, such as with a `case` statement .

Comment: If you can guarantee that one of the radiobuttons is checked then you should raise an exception instead of a simple exit. Once you add another option the exception is your reminder